# Checking for empty or null string in Drools when clause

Tags: java, drools

Is there some convenient way to check if strings are null or blank (including "" or a string with only white spaces) in Drools? Until now I have been using dialect "Java" with expressions like:

```
value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()
```

This seems to work. Just wondering, if there is a more concise way to do it.

Here is an example of a rule using this expression:

```
rule "some rule"
    when
        $container:CC()
        $customer:Customer() from $container.eCustomer
        CustomerPreferenceListType($preferenceList:preferences) from $customer.preferences
        $preference:CT(value == null || value.trim().isEmpty()) from $preferenceList
    then
        $preferenceList.remove($preference);
end
```

Actually you can also use this expression and this too works fine:

```
value == null || value.trim.empty
```

Comment: Concise code can always be obtained by writing functions.

Comment: @laune: True, but is there anything out of the box in Drools for this.

Comment: Is there anything out of the box in Java for this? -- Next, someone comes and asks for the same thing with Integer and 0. Then Double and 0. Then some array and length == 0. And so on. -- It is a good strategy to initialize the fields to something != null as the value for "nothing there" if you have such a value.